# npm package connect-pg-simple webpack issue while creating session

Tags: postgresql, nodejs

Getting issue with connect-pg-simple@8.0.0 package while building app using webpack

Line of code generating below issue

```
"ERROR in ./node_modules/connect-pg-simple/index.js 82:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (82:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   class PGStore extends Store {
|     /** @type {boolean} */
>     #createTableIfMissing;
|     /** @type {boolean} */
|     #disableTouch;
 @ ./server.js 3:0-35 28:16-18"
```